# Is Mac System Integrity Protection defined within the sys/stat.h

Tags: c, linux, macos, darwin

I've done some hunting around on the internet and have not found a good way of programmatically determining if a given file has integrity detection turned on.

I noticed that, unlike most linux headers I have run across, Darwin doesn't define their st_mode bits in the stat struct defined in /sys/stat.h. It seems like the best way to implement this would be to work off the existing sys/stat.h header however, it's obvious why they would not want to be open about it.  Has anyone looked into this more?

### Edit

Bases on Ken Thomases suggestion my if check looks like this.  Looking at the comments in the source it appears as though this should work, however it is still attempting to enter directories such as:
"/Users/<USER>/Library/IdentityServices"
Causing a segmentation fault.  FYI I have tested it with and without preprocessor IFDEF statements.

```
if(
  (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) 
    && ((fileStat.st_flags & SF_RESTRICTED) == 0)
    && (((fileStat.st_mode & 5) == 5)
      || (((fileStat.st_mode & 40) == 40)
        && (fileStat.st_gid == userHomeStat.st_uid))
      || (((fileStat.st_mode & 320) == 320)
        && (fileStat.st_uid == userHomeStat.st_uid))))
 {
   std::cout<< "Decending into --> " << fullPath.c_str() <<std::endl;
   packIndexFrom((fullPath).c_str());
 }
```

### EDIT

```html
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/FileSystemProtections/FileSystemProtections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016462-CH2-SW1
```

I found this on Apple's website.  It seems to indicate that the $HOME/Library area, which is where I am getting hung up falls under some type of restriction, with exclusive r/w access for developers.
Doesn't solve my problem unfortunately.

### Edit

```
Dans-MBP:tmp mreff555$ cd ~/Library/IdentityServices/
Dans-MBP:IdentityServices mreff555$ pwd
/Users/mreff555/Library/IdentityServices
Dans-MBP:IdentityServices mreff555$ ls
ls: .: Operation not permitted
Dans-MBP:IdentityServices mreff555$ 

Dans-MBP:IdentityServices mreff555$ ls -ldO ~/Library/IdentityServices
drwxr-xr-x  9 mreff555  staff  - 288 Apr 14 10:04 /Users/mreff555/Library/IdentityServices
```

Comment: `SF_RESTRICTED` would be in `st_flags`, not `st_mode`. I was pretty clear about that in my answer.

Comment: Still running into issues with the same files.

Comment: What makes you think that /Users/<USER>/Library/IdentityServices is SIP-protected? It's not for me. Basically, nothing in a user directory could be. SIP protects system files. You can use `ls -ldO <path>` to check. It would show "restricted" in the flags column (between group and size).

Comment: that argument isn't recognized my version of "ls".  I found an article on the Apple developer site indicating that the $HOME/Library directory followed some type of special case restricted schema.  Developers only.  However details were quite vague. Appending it to my post.

Comment: That link means the opposite of what you think. It's pointing out that ~/Library is, **by contrast to system directories**, accessible (unprotected). I'm not sure what you mean by the `-ldO` options being unrecognized by your `ls`. They've been supported by the system `ls` for years and years (since 10.6, at least).

Comment: See original post.  I posted an example of the problem statement.  when dirent.h calls attempt to access this directory it results in a segmentation fault.

Comment: I don't see that on two different Mojave systems. Also, that's not quite what I suggested you try. What's the result of `ld -ldO ~/Library/IdentityServices`? (Note that that should only require access to read the contents of ~/Library, not ~/Library/IdentityServices. You could also simply do `ld -ldO ~/Library` and look for the line about the IdentityServices subdirectory.)

Comment: I added it.  See above.

Comment: The output that you show has no "restricted" flag. The "-" between "staff" and "288" means "no flags". Whatever is happening is not related to the SIP-protected file feature. I think you're going to have to add a crash report. For non-GUI apps, there's no crash reporter UI/dialog, but they're still written to ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports.

Comment: I believe it's TCC, not SIP, that's preventing access to ~/Library/IdentityServices .

Comment: Hmmmm.  I think you may be right.  Unfortunately that is a problem because I can't seem to find anything in the documentation about an API.  Perhaps I'll just have to ignore known problem areas for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are flags that are separate from the mode flags. You're looking for the `SF_RESTRICTED` flag in the `st_flags` field of `struct stat`. That flag is, in fact, defined in sys/stat.h.

The mode flags (e.g. `S_IRUSR`) are defined in sys/_types/_s_ifmt.h, which is indirectly included by sys/stat.h.